# Let $f,g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{k}$ be cont. If $D \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is dense on which $f$ and $g$ coincide, then $f(x) = g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{k}$ be continuous. If $D \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a dense subset on which $f$ and $g$ coincide ($f(x) = g(x) \forall x \in D$), then $f(x) = g(x) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

(I know there is a partial solution out there, but I'm trying to get feedback on my attempt)

**Attempt:**
Suppose towards contradiction that $f(x) \neq g(x) \forall x \notin D$.

Given that $D$ is dense means that every point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is either a point of $D$ or a limit point of $D$. If $ x \in D$ then we are done. Assuming that $x$ is a limit point of $D$ this means that there exists a sequence in $D$ such that $x_{n} \to x$, where $x_{n} \in D$ and $x \notin D$. We assumed towards contradiction that $f(x) \neq g(x)$ for all $x \notin D$ but we are also given that $f$ and $g$ are continuous, so with respect to the sequence $x_{n} \in D$ that would mean $f(x_{n}) \neq g(x_{n})$ for all $x_{n} \in D$. Which is a contradiction.

**My Issue:**

I think the idea that I'm trying to express is correct, but I'm concerned about the final part of it because sure the sequences can be equivalent in the set, but at the point of convergence $x$ which is not in the set $D$ I don't see why it could not be the case that $f(x) \neq g(x)$.

Feedback on how to make this crisper if that is indeed all that is missing?

Comment: Correct proof and reasonably clear; ***endorsed, +1***!

Comment: I think it is easier to prove directly, that is if $x \notin D$ then there are $x_k \in D$ such that $x_k \to x$. Since $f(x_k)=g(x_k)$ and $f(x_k) \to f(x)$ we must have $f(x_k) \to g(x)$ and hence $f(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: @RobertLewis: Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: You obtain $f(x_n)\neq g(x_n)$ not necessarily for all $n$ but for large enough $n$. Before that, and to get to it, you need to choose open disjoint sets $U,V$ such that $f(x)\in U$ and $g(x)\in V$. Then, the continuity gives you that there is $N$ such that for $n>N$ you have $f(x_n)\in U$ and $g(x_n)\in V$.

Comment: @copper.hat:  backatcha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, contradiction to $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$ is $\exists x $ such that $f(x) \neq g(x)$, not $f(x) \neq g(x)$ for all $x$. Secondly, in the last part, you only get $\forall N \in \mathbb N$, there exists $m_N>N$ such that $f(x_{m_N}) \neq g(x_{m_N})$. But the idea is good, however it is simplier doing it by converging sequences (assuming you deal with $\mathbb R^n$ with metric). Taking any $x \in \mathbb R^n$ it is a limit of sequence of points $x_m \in D$ because $D$ is dense. Then since $f(x_m) = g(x_m)$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$. But both $f,g$ are continuous, so we can take the limit inside, getting $f(x) = g(x)$.